# Date Time insert error

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, datepicker

I am using bootstrap **date time picker** and when I try to insert selected date time it showing me an error

> "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid date time format: 1292 Incorrect date time value: '21 December 2012 - 03:25 PM' for column 'startDate' at row 1 "

then I used in my controller

```
$iVisitors->startDate = date("Y-d-m H:i:s", strtotime(request('startDate')));
```

but now it stores a default time 1970-01-01 00:00:00 not my selected time. How can I store my selected date time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format of the datetime being passed to php's strtotime() is wrong. You could simply replace the `-` that appears before the time with an empty string using php's str_replace(), i.e.

`$iVisitors->startDate = date("Y-d-m H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('- ', '', request('startDate'))));` 
 so that `21 December 2012 - 03:25 PM` now becomes `21 December 2012 03:25 PM`.

You are getting `1970-01-01 00:00:00` because strtotime is returning false and so php's date is also returning its start date.

You can checkout the [strtotime php manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for more information. You could also easily specify the format being returned from the datepicker script by setting an acceptable format.

Comment: now showing another exception: "ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Creating default object from empty value"

Comment: Kindly check your **request('startDate')** value

Comment: Thank you very much